# How to create codeigniter routes like wordpress

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have an ecommerce website with wordpress, but now i wanna redevelop in CodeIgniter.

I have hundred indexed url in google.

Here's url format that I expexted with CI routes.

I have tried using this code, but when I try to access blog post it will redirect to city page

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'product/city/$1/$2';
```

```
public function city($name) {

}
result : 
www.store.com/kuala-lumpur
```

```
public function category($name, $city) {

}
result : 
www.store.com/bouquet-kuala-lumpur
```

```
public function blog($title) {

}
result : 
www.store.com/this-birthday-gift-will-make-your-boyfriend-surprised
```

City and Category will take from database.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that purpose you need to save urls in database table (permalinks).

on save/update, get title of record and make it user friendly url and save in permalinks.

That table structure can be:

```
id
permalink
entity_type (city, category, blog)
entity_id
```

so based on entity type, it will join on relevant table like city, blog or category and map the urls.

- www.store.com/bouquet-kuala-lumpur
- www.store.com/kuala-lumpur
- www.store.com/this-birthday-gift-will-make-your-boyfriend-surprised